# Hibernate Search: Index an XML String?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have a JPA entity mapped using Hibernate Search.  The entity has a field that will consist of an XML `String`.  Is it possible to index the value of that `String` and perform a search against it?

For example, if my XML `String` looked like:

```
<myElement>
  <myChildElement>Foo</myChildElement>
</myElement>
```

Would it be possible to query for Entities with a field that have `myChildElement` equal to `Foo`?  If so, how would I map the field within the entity?  How do I form the Hibernate Search query?

Comment: Well, of course you can do that. You might need some custom code though. In the end it's more a matter of how to index and query (arbitrary?) XML in Lucene. I haven't used both (HSEARCH and Lucene) in a while but one way to index that might be to create a Lucene field name from the xpath (e.g. `xmlField_myElement_myChildElement`) and store the value `Foo` for that field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's such a good idea to store XML in entity properties; parsing the XML and storing it as an [embeddable object](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_component_embedded) instead of a String field might prove easier in the long run.

But if you have to, yes, you can index that XML-formatted field.

You will have to implement a [custom field bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-filed-bridge). In your implementation, you will use some XML parser, extract the values for the XML nodes that matter to you, and add those values to field in the document. Name the fields as you want, `xmlField_myElement_myChildElement` as suggested by @Thomas will do just fine.

Then you can map your entity property with `@Field(bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = MyFieldBridgeImpl.class))`. You may want to tune [other options](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#field-annotation) though, `analyzer` in particular.

To query the field, nothing particular, do [the usual](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-building-lucene-queries). You may have to call `.ignoreFieldBridge` to avoid your search string being parsed as XML, but that's about it:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder()
        .forEntity( MyEntity.class )
        .get();

Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword()
        .onField("xmlField_myElement_myChildElement")
        .ignoreFieldBridge()
        .matching(searchString)
        .createQuery();

List<MyEntity> results = (List<MyEntity>) fullTextEntityManager
        .createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, MyEntity.class )
        .list();
```